# haskell - check two points in R^2

Tags: haskell

i have given two points.
Now of i need to check if those points are identical, so i do:

```
type datatypePoint = (Float,Float)

anyLine :: datatypePoint -> datatypePoint -> datatypeLine
anyLine a b = [[fst a, fst b] , [snd a, snd b]]
    | (fst a == fst b) && (snd a == snd b) = error "Identical"
    | otherwise = error "Not identical"
```

But i get error:

```
unexpected |
```

anybody could tell me why? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your errors aside, note that 1. [you should use `Double` in Haskell unless there's a specific reason not to do it](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Floating_point) 2. even then, `==`-comparing floating point values is basically doomed to give bad results, because most calculations have small rounding errors in them. – Usually, you want to check only `<` relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few errors here, first off, all types start with upper case letters in Haskell

```
type Point = (Float,Float)

anyLine :: Point -> Point -> Point
```

Next, pattern matching happens **before** the `=` sign.

```
anyLine (a1, a2) (b1, b2)
  | a1 == b1 && a2 == b2 = error "Identical"
  | otherwise            = error "Not identical"
```

And with guards we omit the equality sign.

This could also just be

```
anyLine a b
  | a == b = ...
  | otherwise = ...
```

I think it's well worth the time to read a good Haskell tutorial to learn some of the basic concepts you're missing, I personally favor [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: ok yea thanks, you´re right, do you know any module for solving linear equations?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a result or define cases; you can't do both at the same time.

```
anyLine :: datatypePoint -> datatypePoint -> datatypeLine
anyLine a b
    | (fst a == fst b) && (snd a == snd b) = error "Identical"
    | otherwise = error "Not identical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other folks have already answered the question, but I wanted to point out that this would be even simpler if you used "newtype" and "deriving"

```
newtype Point a = Point (a, a) deriving (Eq)

anyLine a b 
    | a == b = ....
    | otherwise = ....
```

It also doesn't hurt to keep the type a generic, so now this will work for "Point"s of Floats, Ints, etc.